# C# winform login using Ms Access 2013

Tags: c#, database, authentication, ms-access-2013

I am creating a C# windows login form using MS Access 2013.
Login form using User ID(Autonumber) and Password(Short text). 
My problem here is, it always crash(or Syntax error I guess) every time I click the LOGIN button and I can't trace the problem since I'm still inexperience in programming.

Table User

Fields: user_Id(Auto Number), password(short text), name(short text), type(number)

```
    private void btn_Login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_UserId.Text))
            {
                lbl_warningUser.Visible = true;
                lbl_warningUser.Text = "User ID is Empty";
            }
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_Password.Text))
            {
                lbl_warningPass.Visible = true;
                lbl_warningPass.Text = "Password is Empty";
            }
            if (txt_UserId.Text !="" & txt_Password.Text != "")
            {
                string constring = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=Database/Health.accdb;";
                string query = ("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM User WHERE user_Id = @ID AND password = @Pass");
                using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constring))
                using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, con))
                {
                    con.Open();
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", txt_UserId.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pass", txt_Password.Text);

                    int result = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                    if (result > 0)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Successfully Login");
                        con.Close();
                        this.Hide();
                        MainUI m = new MainUI();
                        m.Show();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Incorrect User ID or Password");
                    }

                 con.Close();
                }

            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("  "+ex);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Is it a crash or a (compile-time) syntax error or a runtime syntax error in the query?  Do you get a stack trace or error message?

Comment: it was the catch (Exception ex). in your terms, i think it was a runtime syntax error in the query

Comment: change the catch to ex.innerexception or ex.message to get more visibility to the error, you may also want to redefine your parameters. You are declaring them after the query. Define the parameters first then the query string. How you have it they are undefined at time of creation for the query.

Comment: And what exactly does the exception say?

Comment: the exception was too long but the first phrase starts to mention about "Syntax error in FROM clause"

Comment: Without the error we only can guess at the problem

Answer (score 1):

`User` is a reserved word in MS Access I think, so you need to wrap it in square bracket delimiters. Also, you likely need to specify an alias for the COUNT function result:

```
"SELECT COUNT(*) AS qtyUsers FROM [User] WHERE user_Id = @ID AND password = @Pass"
```

Comment: thank you, i applied the  [User] (with brackets) and it works, thank you

Answer (score 0):

`txt_UserId.Text` has a default return value of string, did you convert the value to an integer then try actually autonumber is integer.
First convert your value and try

```
    Convert.ToInt32(txt_UserId.Text)
```

Comment: I'm thinking his user id is a text value, like a user name ... but may be wrong.